# Can't use : php bin/console doctrine:database:create

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

[image: screenshot]

Hi,
I try to learn Symfony with a video tutorial and i have an issue when i try to use this in terminal:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

I have this message:

> "Too many arguments, expected arguments "command"."

How can I connect to the mysql local website ? What's the address ?

Edit : When i use "root" instead of "whyj06" username i have this

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: have you put mysql connections in env file correclty ?

Comment: Can you screen the output or use https://asciinema.org/ to record your terminal?

Comment: i have this : DATABASE_URL=mysql://whyj06:@127.0.0.1:3306/demo

Comment: i've just uploaded the screenshot Nek

Comment: whyj06 seems like your username. Provide your password in it. DATABASE_URL=mysql://whyj06:YourPassword@127.0.0.1:3306/demo

Comment: Use just command without `argument` here `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

Comment: Thanks Vinoth, but when i had install mysql i just put the username and empty password !

Answer (score 3):

You should execute only `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` without your database name.

Your database name is configured in your config file.

Comment: I tried, and i have this now : "Could not create database `demo` for connection named default
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE DATABASE `demo`':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1044 Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'demo'"

Comment: Probably you have typo user or password. The error clearly says "Access denied". Do your user have grant all privileges? You could try with user `root` without password, if you have installed wampp/xampp.

Comment: i have mamp installed, and if i try with user root i have a new issue, i put the screenshot into the post.

Comment: In both cases there is a problem with your user/password for connection. I'm not familiar with MAMP, but could you test with user `root` and password `root` ?

Comment: I have the same issue, but i think this mysql is different than the mysql installed with mamp... Not the same installation of mysql, so can i link my symfony mysql env to my mamp mysql ?

Comment: Which MySQL is different? I can't understand you, if you think that Symfony has own MySQL server - no Symfony doesn't have own SQL server.

Comment: no i mean, i think when i had installed my environment i have installed another mysql in a different folder of the one used with mamp.

Answer (score 1):

Please check you `.env` file where you specify `DATABASE_URL` variable and adjust it to the schema.

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name
```

if your user name is `whyj06` and there is no password, modify your url to:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://whyj06@127.0.0.1:3306/demo
```

after that try to running `doctrine:database:create` without any additional arguments:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

Please notice that if your database was already created this command will return error. To avoid that you can add `--if-not-exists` argument to create database only if it does not exist yet.

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create --if-not-exists
```